# Add page as static html into another page

Tags: include, pages

Is there a way to include a wordpress Page into another one? I'm not just talking about getting the content using get_page(), but to import the whole page (theme + content). I have been looking around for hours for a way to achieve this but I can't find a way, I guess it's a pretty unusual thing to try to do, but it's necessary for what I want to do with my site.

What I want to achieve is this:

Page1 uses this template:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: page-template1
*/
?>

<div id="content">
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
 <div class="post">
 <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></h2>
 <div class="entrytext">
  <?php the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>
 </div>
 </div>
 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>

<div>
Hello
import_page("page2");
</div>
```

Page2 uses this template:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: page-template2
*/
?>

<div>
World

<div id="content">
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
 <div class="post">
 <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></h2>
 <div class="entrytext">
  <?php the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>
 </div>
 </div>
 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>

</div>
```

Result:

```
<div>
World

<div id="content">
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
 <div class="post">
 <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></h2>
 <div class="entrytext">
  <?php the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>
 </div>
 </div>
 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>

</div>
<div>
Hello
<div>
World

<div id="content">
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
 <div class="post">
 <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></h2>
 <div class="entrytext">
  <?php the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>
 </div>
 </div>
 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe an explanation of why you want to do this would help? What is the point, in human terms?

Comment: Also, I notice that your title states "add static html". You aren't trying to add static HTML. You are adding dynamic-- PHP generated-- HTML. Can you explain the discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`locate_template()`](http://queryposts.com/function/locate_template/).

```
locate_template( 'page-template2', true );
```

Comment: But I wouldn't get the contents of the page then, only the template, right?

Comment: Take a look at the source. This _requires_ and loads the file. Just try it.

Comment: @LukasK, You may not get the results you want though. Unless your second template has its own query-- looks like it doesn't-- it will try to Loop through the same query results used by template1 and that query hasn't been reset.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Double that. But hard to keep track with a constantly evolving question :P